# How to change size of this text box?

Tags: html, css, salesforce

I've created the following input label/text box, but its huge and runs across the page. Is there anyway I can change the size of the textbox so that it's a lot smaller than it currently is? My code below:

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon">
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">$</span>
    <input id="text-input-01" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: I'm doing this in Lightning, so my CSS is already installed. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to edit the CSS and have to find another way to resize this. I fsomeone can help me out, that would really help.

Comment: Can you add a style attribute to your textbox and change the width and height properties inline? For example `<div class="slds-form-element" style="width:50px; height:50px">`

Comment: If you want to avoid inline css, you can also try linking to an additional css file and use the !important tag on the styles (i.e. width: 300px !important;)  Not really the best practice either, but its another option.

Comment: @carmouche Sweet, I went ahead and got it implemented. Could you perhaps show me how to reposition the box to wherever I want in the page?

Comment: If you have more specific questions, it would be good to open a new question or search to see if it has already been answered.  But, as a starting point, you can try using absolute positioning using `position: absolute`

Answer (score 2):

If css is absolutely out of the question you could always just add an inline style rule. This is generally not considered best practice, but if that's all you're left with you may not have another option.

```html
<div style="width:300px;" class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon">
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">$</span>
    <input id="text-input-01" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually pretty good. Could you perhaps show me how to do this in CSS anyways? I'll try and see if I can implement it.

Comment: <style>.slds-form-element { width: 300px; }</style>

Comment: Just keep in mind they could have style rules for the elements within that, so without seeing the css we can't know for sure. You can do the same with those elements as well though.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <style>
            input, button, select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
        </style>
        <div class="slds-form-element">
  <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="text-input-01">Input Label</label>
  <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-fixed-addon">
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">$</span>`enter code here`
    <input id="text-input-01" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Placeholder Text" />
    <span class="slds-form-element__addon">%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```